# Send email when 'submit' button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a 4 page ASP.NET form which is storing data in the session. When the 'Submit' button on the 3rd page is clicked i want the details entered to be emailed to my hotmail account but i can't seem to get it to work as it always falls stright into my `catch`.

**HTML is**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Columns="50"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subject:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubject" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem>Ask a question</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Report a bug</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Customer support ticket</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message:</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" Columns="40" Rows="6" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**Code for my `onclick` is**

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Create the msg object to be sent
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        //Add your email address to the recipients
        msg.To.Add("**SHOULD THIS BE MY EMAIL ADDRESS?**");
        //Configure the address we are sending the mail from **- NOT SURE IF I NEED THIS OR NOT?**
        //MailAddress address = new MailAddress("SenderAddress@gmail.com");
        //msg.From = address;
        //Append their name in the beginning of the subject
        msg.Subject = txtName.Text + " :  " + ddlSubject.Text;
        msg.Body = txtMessage.Text;

        //Configure an SmtpClient to send the mail.
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 465);
        client.EnableSsl = true; //only enable this if your provider requires it
        //Setup credentials to login to our sender email address ("UserName", "Password")
        NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("MY@EMAIL ADDRESS", "**SHOULD THIS BE MY PASSOWRD?**");
        client.Credentials = credentials;

        //Send the msg
        client.Send(msg);

        //Display some feedback to the user to let them know it was sent
        lblResult.Text = "Your message was sent!";

        //Clear the form
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtMessage.Text = "";
    }
    catch
    {
        //If the message failed at some point, let the user know
        lblResult.Text = "Your message failed to send, please try again.";
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out.

I got the SMTP details from http://www.serversmtp.com/en/smtp-hotmail but it always fails

Comment: what error you are receiving?

Comment: *but i can't seem to get it to work* doesn't help anyone.. you need to explain more in detail.

Comment: [Eating all the exceptions](http://i.imgur.com/Gj44qoW.jpg) is the best way to get an error-free application.

Comment: @Izzy, @Tjaart van der Walt it fall's stright into my `catch`

Comment: update `catch` as `catch(Exception ex)` and read what's in ex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your code, try to use the same email for From and To since you are sending it to yourself and also use your hotmail password as part of the NetworkCredential instantiation:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Create the msg object to be sent
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            //Add your email address to the recipients
            msg.To.Add("youremail@hotmail.com");
            //Configure the address we are sending the mail from **- NOT SURE IF I NEED THIS OR NOT?**
            MailAddress address = new MailAddress("youremail@hotmail.com");
            msg.From = address;
            //Append their name in the beginning of the subject
            msg.Subject = txtName.Text + " :  " + ddlSubject.Text;
            msg.Body = txtMessage.Text;

            //Configure an SmtpClient to send the mail.
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 465);
            client.EnableSsl = true; //only enable this if your provider requires it
            //Setup credentials to login to our sender email address ("UserName", "Password")
            NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("youremail@hotmail.com", "YourPassword");
            client.Credentials = credentials;

            //Send the msg
            client.Send(msg);

            //Display some feedback to the user to let them know it was sent
            lblResult.Text = "Your message was sent!";

            //Clear the form
            txtName.Text = "";
            txtMessage.Text = "";
        }
        catch
        {
            //If the message failed at some point, let the user know
            lblResult.Text = "Your message failed to send, please try again.";
        }
    }
```

Also make sure that 465 port number is correct for smtp.live.com. You can try 587 instead [Send Email from Yahoo!, GMail, Hotmail (C#)](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/520998/Send-Email-from-Yahoo-GMail-Hotmail-Csharp)

Comment: the reason why mine was failing was due to the 'From' as i had it commmentd out also i have chnaged it to use port 465

Comment: Could you pleas have a look at my new post for emails and see if you can help on that one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747419/can-you-use-an-if-statement-for-body-for-email-functionality-onclick-of-a-butto