# Can You Use An If Statement For .Body For Email Functionality Onclick Of A Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a button on a page when sends the details to me in an email.  This is working fine but i have an issue as one of the questions during my process is a raido button selection. The selected option is working fine on my confirmation page but as its a radio button i'll need an `if` statement for my email as one of the id's will be blank.

Does anyone know how i can do this.

Below is the code for my `.body` of the email

```
msg.Body = Label1.Text + " " + Session["pg1input"].ToString()
           + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
           Label2.Text + " " + Session["pg1dd"].ToString()
           + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
           Label3.Text + " " + Session["pg2"].ToString()
           + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
           Label4.Text + " " + Session["pg2Yes"].ToString()
           + Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
           Label4.Text + " " + Session["pg2No"].ToString();
```

From the code above, the following is the radio button row so either 'pg2Yes' will be blank or 'pg2No' will be blank depending on the radio button selected

```
Label4.Text + " " + Session["pg2Yes"].ToString()
+ Environment.NewLine.ToString() +
Label4.Text + " " + Session["pg2No"].ToString();
```

Id prefer if i just have one label4 displayed and the radio button selected.

I did try

```
Label4.Text + " " + Session["pg2Yes"].ToString() + Session["pg2No"].ToString();
```

But this casued the email not to be sent.

The HTML below is what i have used on the confirmation page to display the relevent radio button selected

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
          <asp:Label ID="Label4" class="col-md-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Kids?"></asp:Label>
          <div class="col-md-3 form-control-static">                            
               <% if (Session["pg2Yes"] == "Yes")
               {%>
                    <%=Session["pg2Yes"] %>
               <%}

              if (Session["pg2No"] == "No")
              {%>
                    <%=Session["pg2No"] %>
              <%} %>
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't belive after nearly a month of trying sort this out, its just come to me, Just use the same `session` name for both radio buttons, and guess what it worked.

Updated `.cs` code

```
    if (PhoneRadioButton.Checked)
    {
        Session["PrefContactRadioButton"] = PhoneRadioButton.Checked ? "Phone" : "";
    }
    else if (EmailRadioButton.Checked)
    {
        Session["PrefContactRadioButton"] = EmailRadioButton.Checked ? "Email" : "";
    }
```

Then updated my confirmation page to call my new `session` variable

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="Step01ContactMethod" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 control-label" runat="server" Text="Preferred method of contact:"></asp:Label>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-9 form-control-static">                            
            <%=Session["PrefContactRadioButton"] %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And finaly updated my confirmation page email body

```
msg.Body = Step01ContactMethod.Text + " " + Session["PrefContactRadioButton"].ToString();
```

And voila it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`?:` conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to set which radio button value you intend to concat with the `Label4.Text`.

```
Label4.Text + " " + Session["pg2Yes"].ToString() == "Yes" 
    ? Session["pg2Yes"].ToString() 
    : Session["pg2No"].ToString();
```

Comment: @Oluwafemi When I add this line for some reason my emails come through blank but if I comment it out and re-send it, it then works. I can't figure out what bit of code can be causing this, can you?

Comment: @murday1983 are you still stuck on this?

Comment: @gunr2171 thanks for the comment. I have updated my code.

Comment: @Oluwafemi yes I am still stuck on it.  I can see that you say you have updated the code but when I view your original and updated code line they are identical

Comment: can you check if these Sessions has values?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes the session does have the values but as I said if I use the code above, all values are removed from my email

Comment: Do you have other suggestions as I am getting the value back but the email sent is completely empty but if I remove this line of code it works again